# PHP MYSQL - Search and Sort Query Results

Tags: php, mysql, database

hoping someone can help here.

I'm in the process of creating a site which will list horse racing tips, which are pulled from a MySQL database using PHP scripts. I've managed to create the database, which has five columns (ID, RaceDate, Location, RaceTime and Horse) and I've created some scripts that query the RaceDate column and only display the rows which match the current date. See below:

```
<?php
    $db_host = 'xxxxx'; // Server Name
    $db_user = 'xxxxx'; // Username
    $db_pass = 'xxxxx'; // Password
    $db_name = 'xxxxx'; // Database Name

    $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
        if (!$conn) {
            die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
        }

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM Horses WHERE Date(RaceDate) = Date(NOW())';
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

?>
```

I then have another bit of php further down my page which echo's the data to screen, formatted in a nice table.

```
<?php
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$row['Location'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['RaceTime'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Horse'].'</td>
            </tr>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '0 results';
    }
        $conn->close();
?>
```

That's all works great, but spits out everything in a big list. What I'd really like to be able to do is split the results up depending on the race location.

So, for example, there may be 5 races @ location1, 5 @ location2 and 5 @ location3. Rather than have 15 races listed one after the other, I'd like it split into 3 groups/tables. Is there a way to search through the Location column of my query data and determine what racecourses are listed, then echo the data to screen?

```
e.g IF Location = Wolverhampton
        THEN echo to table 1
    ELSE IF Location = Ayr
        THEN echo to table 2
    ELSE IF Location = Llos Fas
        THEN echo to table 3
    (etc, if more Locations exist)
```

Answer (score 0):

My comment just complicated things, this is simpler way to do it.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     if($row['Location'] === 'location1')
     {
        echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['Location'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['RaceTime'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['Horse'].'</td>
        </tr>';
     }else if($row['Location'] === 'location2')
     {
        echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['Location'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['RaceTime'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['Horse'].'</td>
        </tr>';
     }else if($row['Location'] === 'location3')
     {
        echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['Location'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['RaceTime'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['Horse'].'</td>
        </tr>';
     }
     // And so on....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work. Every time the if/else if loops, it adds the 'Location' in before the entry. Something like:

e.g. LOCATION1 Location1 13:30 Horse1
LOCATION1 Location1 14:00 Horse2
LOCATION1 Location1 14:30 Horse3
LOCATION2 Location2 15:30 Horse4
etc

Even if I take out the Location $row, its still adding the location before every entry. Your code has helped though - I feel like I'm closer to solving this than I was.

Comment: Try now, I started writing answer in different way, then got idea to make it simpler but I forgot to delete a few lines.

Comment: Thanks. I think this more or less does what I need it to. :)